# Jmeter run 2 test plans sequentially command line

Tags: maven, jmeter, automated-tests

I have 2 test plans for 2 different processes that I want to test using Jmeter; both scripts are implemented and can be run individually via the Jmeter GUI.

However, is it possible to run **one** test plan using the command line, and then **once** the first test plan finishes, the second test plan gets kicked off. Basically, I want to run one test plan after another: **NOT** at the same time...

Eventually we want to put these 2 test plans on a server and have them run one after the other using some maven script, but for now is there any way to accomplish this using Jmeter's command line?

Comment: Just call jmeter twice (with 1st and 2nd script) using batch or shell script? What is the catch here?

Comment: @KirilS so we have two jmx files. The first one needs to be completely executed successfully before the second test plan gets fired. We don't want them to be done in parallel, one at a time.

Comment: Batch/shell script won't run commands on parallel, so if you have a script
`jmeter -t first_test.jmx`
`jmeter -t second_test.jmx `
they will run one after the other. What else are you missing?

Comment: So just appending a -t [name of jmx file] will continue stringing together scripts to be run? Lastly, how can I store the results for each file? Or is there a way to aggregate them all into one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) just run your files using shell script like:

```
jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result1.jtl
jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l result2.jtl
```

You can also pass the same file via `-l` command-line option, results of `test2.jmx` will be appended to the results of `test1.jmx`.

For Maven execution just copy both `.jmx` scripts to `src/test/jmeter` folder of your project - Maven will execute the tests sequentially.

After test execution you will be able to find results files under `target/jmeter/results` folder, one file per .jmx script. The results can be merged together via i.e. [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool

More information:

- [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)